# Tracking version of Terraform templates

Tags: devops, terraform

I want to include the Terraform orchestration process in my Continuous Integration pipelines. The idea is that each time someone modifies a Terraform template, a new version is bumped up and a snapshot is saved on a repository somewhere, like Nexus.

In a very naive approach, I was thinking of putting a comment on the top of every Terraform template file like this: `# Version 1.0.0` and on every release I look into this string and bump it up to `# Version 1.0.1`.

Is there however, a recommended way of doing it, the Terraform way?

Comment: What's wrong with just storing your Terraform configuration and modules in Git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a terraform S3 backend with terraboard view.

By this way, the state file goes to S3 bucket whenever a change happens. Terraboard gives a good UI to view/compare the versions/states.

https://github.com/camptocamp/terraboard#use-with-docker

Remember: AWS S3 needs to have Versioning enabled.

Thanks.